# Unicode in String

Tags: java

```
String text =
" Java "
+ " \ u006B \ u0065 \ u006E \ u006E \ u0074 "
+ " \ u0055 \ u006E \ u0069 \ u0063 \ u006F \ u0064 \ u0065 \ u0021 ";

System . out . println( text );
```

I can't resolve this problem guys please help me out

Comment: What problem is that?

Comment: Why do you have a space after each \?

Answer (score 0):

remove the space after the "\"

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

   String text = " Java " + " \u006B \u0065 \u006E \u006E \u0074 " + "\u0055 \u006E \u0069 \u0063 \u006F \u0064 \u0065 \u0021 ";


       System.out.print(text);
        }

    }
```

**output:**

```
 Java  k e n n t U n i c o d e !
```